# Is it safe to read a value from an URL with parse_url?

Tags: php, url, parse-url

For some reason I can't get the `$_GET` variable to do anything so I used a work around by just modifying the URL with a string at the end with a `?` and reading that into my code with the parse_url function and now I wanted to ask if that is a stupid fix in any way and if I should not do that.

example on how I did it

```
$url = "http://website.com/page?value";

$token = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

So In the end I just get the value inside $token

Comment: That querystring looks incomplete. It should say `value=1` or something similar at the end.

Comment: are you using `.htaccess` for `page` path?

Comment: What if you go to `http://website.com/page?value=1` (as @ADyson suggest) and `print_r($_GET);` on your page?

Comment: _"I cant get the $_GET variable to do anything"_ - What are you expecting the $_GET-variable "to do"?

Comment: If I do that with the value=1 and all it doesn't work thats kinda why I did it the way I posted it here, and it works. My question was more if it brings any huge security risks or something similar to the table that I am not aware of

Comment: We can't answer that because we can't see what you're doing with the data afterwards. But $_GET should definitely work anyway, from what you've described, and is more efficient than having to hunt for the parameter within the array returned by parse_url. (And that's no more or less secure than what you've shown. It's what you do with it afterwards that might have an impact on security.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the url like this:
http://website.com/page=5

Then get the value using below format:

```
echo "page value" . $_GET['page'];
```

if you want to pass more than one variable:
http://website.com/page=5&id=1

```
echo "page value" .  $_GET['page'] .''.$_GET['id'] ;
```

I hope this answer will be helpful for you.

Comment: Can you get `$_GET` variables without having `?` as a starting guideline? I didnt know that.

Comment: @Patrick no, you can not, at least if there is no additional rewriting/routing in place. `http://website.com/?page=5` and `http://website.com/?page=5&id=1` respectively would be the _correct_ URLs to pass query string data to the root index file here.

Comment: Instead of get method try post method  . whether its possible from your side ?